# upstart always re-starts mysql and will not re-read the conf file

Tags: mysql, upstart

I am using upstart on OEL 6, an old version 0.6.5.

I created a conf file to start/stop mysql with a pre-stop section and respawn.
Now when I want to change the conf file, I cannot get it re-read because each time I stop mysql it gets re-started and the conf file changes are only re-read when the job stops!

I have seen on a upstart bug list that this behaviour changes in latter releases, so that a respawn does not happen when the goal is to stop.

So what can I do now, reboot the machine?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Pete

Comment: Update the machine first.

Comment: Hi, I cannot update the machine in the environment I am working in, I'll have to arrange for a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In the end a reboot was the only way to go. Of course when the machine came back up all was well as the new version of the conf file was read.

Pete